# Replacing the previous text in the console

Tags: c#

I have a program that performs its actions through classes, writes at the start of execution...Let me show you

```
public static void Start()
{
Console.WriteLine("Clean");
...
Console.WriteLine("Clean: Done");
}
```

Yes, but this is in multithreading somewhere 7 classes, and it is difficult to see line by line what was done

I want to make it so that the text is displayed, and after the end of the class in the console, "Done!" for example, I found how to do it through Replace, but in txt files, find text and replace, but I did not find it in the console.Help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Console.SetCursorPosition method.

Check the documentation and the code examples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-5.0